# Output CSV column headers in Apache Camel

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, marshalling

Is it possible to output a header row in the "Marshalling a Map to CSV" example on this page? http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

```
Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
body.put("foo", "abc");
body.put("bar", 123);

from("direct:start")
.marshal().csv()
.to("mock:result");
```

Outputs:

```
abc,123
```

Desired output:

```
foo,bar
abc,123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Camel 2.15 onwards which supports configuring headers. See the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

And the unit tests of camel-csv have some examples
https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-csv

Comment: Is it possible to output a single header (orderId,item,amount) in CsvMarshalPipeDelimiterTest.testCsvMarshal() without knowing the LinkedHashMap.keySet() until runtime? Another way of asking the question is, is it possible to output a single header (A,C) in CsvMarshalTest.shouldHandleColumns() without knowing that the Map.keySet() is [A,C] (until runtime) in createRouteBuilder()?

Comment: Not sure but yeah sounds like a good idea, to use the key names as headers. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket

Comment: does that mean if headers are not configured - they will not be present in the csv? Suppose I have result set from jdbc, the headers of the columns do not appear in csv when I do just <marshal><csv/></marshal>.

Answer (score 0):

I defined an Aggregator of `List<Map<String,String>>` that added the `Map.get(0).keySet()` as element 0 of the aggregated `List` the first time it was invoked (e.g. `oldExchange==null`). When aggregation completed, I invoked `marshal().csv()` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using spring xml

```
Using spring xml

      <multicast stopOnException="true">
    <pipeline>
      <log message="saving table ${headers.tablename} header to ${headers.CamelFileName}..."/>
      <setBody>     
<groovy>request.headers.get('CamelJdbcColumnNames').join(";") + "\n"</groovy>
      </setBody>
      <to uri="file:output"/>
    </pipeline>

    <pipeline>
      <log message="saving table ${headers.tablename} rows to ${headers.CamelFileName}..."/>
      <marshal>
        <csv delimiter=";" headerDisabled="false" useMaps="true"/>
      </marshal>
      <to uri="file:output?fileExist=Append"/>
    </pipeline>
  </multicast>
```

http://www.redaelli.org/matteo-blog/2019/05/24/exporting-database-tables-to-csv-files-with-apache-camel/

Bye matteo